# Can you delete boot sector using python?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, bootloader, system32

Is there a way to delete the boot sector of Windows using Python script? or any other important file of Windows like system32?

Can the Python code  `os.remove()`  be used to remove these important files? I saw it in a video in which a code was written: `os.remove("C:\\Windows\\System32")`.

Comment: Ultimately, if there is a Windows API to do something, you can call that from Python. What legitimate reason would you have to remove System32 or the boot sector though?